# Rotating Point Symbols in ArcGIS Javascript API 4.5 SceneLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using a SceneView and SceneLayer with the ArcGIS Javascript API 4.5. My SceneLayer has point features and I want to display them as cones with the point of the cone pointing to the ground. I can get them to render as cones with this renderer:

```
var renderer = {
    type: 'simple',  // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
    symbol: {  // symbol type required for rendering point geometries
        type: 'point-3d',  // autocasts as new PointSymbol3D()
        symbolLayers: [{  // renders points as volumetric objects
            type: 'object',  // autocasts as new ObjectSymbol3DLayer()
            resource: { primitive: 'cone' },  // renders points as cones
            width: 15
        }]
    }
};
```

However the cones are pointing the wrong direction and I can't find a good example of how to rotate them. Does anyone have any examples of this?

I would also like these points to scale based on zoom. I know that scale-based symbol sizing can be done for a map view but I haven't found how to do this with a scene view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rotate that cone, just use `inverted-cone`
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-ObjectSymbol3DLayer.html#resource

if you really want to rotate that 3D object, add `tilt:180` in `symbolLayers` property https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-ObjectSymbol3DLayer.html#properties-summary

Comment: Thanks inverted-cone makes it easy. Any thoughts on the second part of my question about changing the size of the cone based on scale or zoom?

Comment: there is an example (`// scale-dependent size`) containing  `expression: "view.scale",` in my last link above, that could help. Otherwise, you could make it programatically, with a few math on the dimensions of the cone relative to the scale...

Comment: expression is deprecated in 4.5 and viewExpression: '$view.scale' only works for MapViews. However, I did find this link with an example of changing the renderer every time the map zooms: https://community.esri.com/message/671221-re-is-it-possible-to-scale-the-size-of-a-objectsymbol3dlayer-based-on-the-zoom-level
That does what I want.